# Matlab GPIB - how to read Message AVailable from Status Byte Register?

Tags: matlab, visa, gpib

as the title says...

I want to check the [SBR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/gpib-overview.html#f13-38547) register of device connected over [GPIB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE-488). I am interested in reading the MAV bit 4, which should be set if instrument has something it would like to send me.

The problem is, that in order to check the [SBR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/gpib-overview.html#f13-38547), I inevitably have to send another query ([`*STB?`](http://rfmw.em.keysight.com/spdhelpfiles/33500/webhelp/US/Content/__I_SCPI/IEEE-488_Subsystem.htm#STB)), which clears the device output buffer by default. **In other words, whenever I check if there is something to read, I remove it just by looking.** Here is code to reproduce it, problem is at the last call to `fscanf()`:

```
>> fid = gpib('agilent', 7, 26);
>> fopen(fid)
>> fprintf(fid, '*SRE 255; *SRE?') % Enable everything in SBR
>> fscanf(fid) % Returns +191 as expected (255 - 64 for MSS)

>> fprintf(fid, '*IDN?') % Make any query...
>> fprintf(fid, '*STB?') % Read SBR
   % The line above generates device Query Error (beep)

>> fscanf(fid) % << Returns +0 !!!

>> fclose(fid) % Just to prevent flames :]
```

I suspect, that there is some way to check the SBR without querying the device, but I could not find anything. MATLAB help for VISA drivers is silent on the topic of communicating directly with the driver or the bus.

I also tried to check for [BusManagementStatus](http://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/busmanagementstatus.html) with no avail.

For reference, I am using `MATLAB R2011b`, with 32-bit `Agilent VISA` drivers, and the GPIB enabled device is `Agilent E4980A LCR Meter`. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think that I figured it out. Please correct me if I am wrong...

First of all I need to anticipate the need to check for available message, because in my solution I won't be able to check for Error Queue, Master Summary, and other bits, that are set in [SBR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/gpib-overview.html#f13-38547).

Then, before my actual commands (that may produce some output), I need to mask the [Service Request Enable Register (SRER)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/gpib-overview.html#f13-38538) to only allow MAV bit. Thats done like so (following from example in question):

```
>> fprintf(fid, '*SRE 16');
>> fprintf(fid, '...ACTUAL COMMANDS THAT ARE TO BE EXECUTED...');
```

Now I can check, whether the device sends a service request, using the aforementioned [`BusManagementStatus`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/busmanagementstatus.html) command. The following command returns true iff there is MAV bit set in SBR.

```
>> strcmp(fid.BusManagementStatus.ServiceRequest, 'on')
```

The disadvantage is that there is no way to check for errors during my `ACTUAL COMMANDS` execution. If I do so, it might produce errors... :]